# How to disable -mcall-linux in gcc

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, powerpc

I am cross compiling code for powerpc64-linux platform using gcc from MINGW. We need to use the gcc option -msdata=sysv. We need to use both the 64-bit and the 32-bit versions. When compiling in the 64-bit version it gives the error -msdata=sysv is incompatible with -mcall-linux. I am not explicitly setting the option -mcall-linux. I need to disable this option. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check `-v` and `gcc --dumpspecs` output. Specs may be used to add some options (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html).

Comment: OK, this is mainly for my own curiosity: why MINGW? You're not likely to be wanting a minimal GNU environment under Windows on POWER, is there a reason you need to use that compiler?

Comment: Well our company runs power system simulations on POWERPC hardware. The software runs on windows machines. We compile the code in windows computers and send the machine code to the hardware and run the simulation and get the results back on windows PC. That is the reason for MinGW.

Comment: Is the target running a full operating system? If yes, which one?

Comment: It is not a full OS. We do not use RAM. All the executables are loaded in the processor cache. I think I found the problem the -msdata=sysv only works for embedded 32 bit targets.